# How to list text files without a .txt file extension?

Tags: command-line, file-format, ls

For example, how can I replicate:

```
ls *.txt
```

when my text files are missing the `.txt` ending, and as far as extensions go appear the same as many other types of file?

Alternatively, is it possible to list specifically just the files which have NO file extension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To match files that do not have an extension at all, you can use the command

```
ls | grep -v '\.'
```

To match files that do not have a `.txt` extension, you can use the command

```
ls | grep -v '\.txt'
```

This will pass the list of files in the current directory to `grep`, which will remove all file names that have a `.` (or `.txt` for the second command) in them.

Comment: Thankyou! This answered my question.

Additionally, is it possible to use the same grep tool with other commands? For instance, with todos? (to convert line endings)

Comment: Yes, `grep` can be used with any command. The `|` symbol is used to pass output from one command to another, and `grep` will match lines that have (or don't have) specific text. But if you want to modify the text (other than just printing matching lines), you should take a look at the `sed` command.

Comment: To find only text files (excluding directories and binaries) use: `ls --classify | grep -v '/'.'*'`

Answer (score 6):

With `ls -ignore="PATTERN"` you can exclude files from a ls result.

For example, `ls --ignore="*.txt"` to ignore txt files.

Answer (score 3):

Simply negate your pattern (note: `shopt -s extglob` is required).

To display all files without extension:

```
ls !(*.*)
```

To show non-`txt` files, try:

```
ls !(*.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `ls -SX1|less` will sort by extension in a single column and files without one will be moved to the top. Piping through less as in the example is suggested for directories with more than a few files to limit output to a screen full at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer avoiding the use of grep for simple listing operations.

In order to avoid using `grep`,

I recommend using `ls !(*.*)` to find files with no file extension,
and

`ls -I "*.gz" -I "*.tz"` or `ls --ignore={"*.jpg","*.png","*.bmp"}`

to exclude specific file extensions